# Real Time Disparity Map Project: Colormap Disparity not Recognized (OpenCV Python StereoBM)

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, matplotlib

My python code below is intended to get a real time disparity map with decent accuracy. Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import sys
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
# Check if camera opened successfully
if (cap.isOpened()== False and cap2.isOpened()== False):
  print("Error opening video stream or file")

# Read until video is completed
while(cap.isOpened() and cap2.isOpened()):
  # Capture frame-by-frame
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  ret2, frame2 = cap2.read()
  if ret == True and ret2 == True:

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Frame',frame)
    cv2.imshow('Frame2',frame2)
    framegray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    frame2gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('Gray1', framegray)
    cv2.imshow('Gray2', frame2gray)
    stereo = cv2.StereoBM_create(numDisparities=16, blockSize=15)
    disparity = stereo.compute(framegray, frame2gray)
    #minVal, maxVal, randval, dontcare = cv2.minMaxLoc(disparity)
    #disparity.convertTo(dispweird, CV_8UC1, 255.0/(maxVal - minVal), -minVal * 255.0/(maxVal - minVal));
    #disparitywithcolor = cv2.applyColorMap(dispweird, cv2.COLORMAP_JET)
    plt.imshow(disparity,'disparity')
    plt.show()
    delay(1000)
    # Press Q on keyboard to  exit
    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
      break

  # Break the loop
  else:
    break

# When everything done, release the video capture object
cap.release()

# Closes all the frames
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here is my commmand line output:

Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                File "cameratest.py", line 31, in                                                                                                                                                         plt.imshow(disparity,'disparity')                                                                                                                                                             File "C:\Users\Adithya Kumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 3205, in imshow                                                              **kwargs)                                                                                                                                                                                     File "C:\Users\Adithya Kumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib__init__.py", line 1855, in inner                                                             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                                              File "C:\Users\Adithya Kumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_axes.py", line 5485, in imshow                                                          resample=resample, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                                                  File "C:\Users\Adithya Kumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 824, in **init**                                                              **kwargs                                                                                                                                                                                      File "C:\Users\Adithya Kumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 228, in **init**                                                              cm.ScalarMappable.**init**(self, norm, cmap)                                                                                                                                                  File "C:\Users\Adithya Kumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cm.py", line 203, in **init**                                                                 self.cmap = get_cmap(cmap)                                                                                                                                                                    File "C:\Users\Adithya Kumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cm.py", line 168, in get_cmap                                                                 % (name, ', '.join(sorted(cmap_d))))                                                                                                                                                        ValueError: Colormap disparity is not recognized. Possible values are: Accent, Accent_r, Blues, Blues_r, BrBG, BrBG_r, BuGn, BuGn_r, BuPu, BuPu_r, CMRmap, CMRmap_r, Dark2, Dark2_r, GnBu, GnBu_r, Greens, Greens_r, Greys, Greys_r, OrRd, OrRd_r, Oranges, Oranges_r, PRGn, PRGn_r, Paired, Paired_r, Pastel1, Pastel1_r, Pastel2, Pastel2_r, PiYG, PiYG_r, PuBu, PuBuGn, PuBuGn_r, PuBu_r, PuOr, PuOr_r, PuRd, PuRd_r, Purples, Purples_r, RdBu, RdBu_r, RdGy, RdGy_r, RdPu, RdPu_r, RdYlBu, RdYlBu_r, RdYlGn, RdYlGn_r, Reds, Reds_r, Set1, Set1_r, Set2, Set2_r, Set3, Set3_r, Spectral, Spectral_r, Wistia, Wistia_r, YlGn, YlGnBu, YlGnBu_r, YlGn_r, YlOrBr, YlOrBr_r, YlOrRd, YlOrRd_r, afmhot, afmhot_r, autumn, autumn_r, binary, binary_r, bone, bone_r, brg, brg_r, bwr, bwr_r, cividis, cividis_r, cool, cool_r, coolwarm, coolwarm_r, copper, copper_r, cubehelix, cubehelix_r, flag, flag_r, gist_earth, gist_earth_r, gist_gray, gist_gray_r, gist_heat, gist_heat_r, gist_ncar, gist_ncar_r, gist_rainbow, gist_rainbow_r, gist_stern, gist_stern_r, gist_yarg, gist_yarg_r, gnuplot, gnuplot2, gnuplot2_r, gnuplot_r, gray, gray_r, hot, hot_r, hsv, hsv_r, inferno, inferno_r, jet, jet_r, magma, magma_r, nipy_spectral, nipy_spectral_r, ocean, ocean_r, pink, pink_r, plasma, plasma_r, prism, prism_r, rainbow, rainbow_r, seismic, seismic_r, spring, spring_r, summer, summer_r, tab10, tab10_r, tab20, tab20_r, tab20b, tab20b_r, tab20c, tab20c_r, terrain, terrain_r, viridis, viridis_r, winter, winter_r

You can see from the commented out code that I tried to convert my disparity map output from stereoBM to an image so that I could colorize it, but for some reason, this isn't working. Please let me know if you have a solution for this issue.

Comment: The code you show is c code, not python. Where is the code that produces the python traceback? And what is `imshow("disparity", disp8);` doing? At the end the error tells you that `"disparity"` is not a valid colormap. So maybe you need to change that to `imshow("viridis", disp8);` but one can only guess here with the incomplete code provided.

Comment: Hello Ernest, my bad! I pasted in the wrong code. Let me update the question

Comment: Hello @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I have just updated the code. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Well, I guess my previous comment holds: You need to use a valid colormap, e.g. `plt.imshow(disparity,'viridis')`

Comment: Hello Ernest, Thank you for your help! I actually solved this problem, so I will mark it solved, but I am now having an updated problem. Here is link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53230263/error-for-disparity-map-code-cvstereosgbmimplcompute-215-opencv